# JSON time service "json-time.appspot.com" is broken. Anyone have a replacement?

Tags: jquery, json, clock, utc

http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=GMT has been broken for a while now... at least a month. This service returns the current time in jsonp, and I have a jquery plugin that uses it to determine the correct time. I'm under the assumption that this service is permanently down since it's been down for a long time and I can't find any posts by the author as to it's status. Does anyone know of a service that I can use that returns the correct time in JSON or XML?

Thanks!

Comment: [now.http.org](http://now.httpbin.org/) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32544360/1016065)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can set up your own: https://github.com/simonw/json-time

Comment: Interesting, but I would prefer to use an existing service that is currently running. I honestly don't want to have to manage this piece of the puzzle.